# IntelliJ's Idea Server Plugin

Tags: rubymine

I don't understand how to upload settings to the central server with Idea Server Plugin. I've logged into my JetBrains account, but I don't see any additional screens to do anything. I am using RubyMine, but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please [refer to the FAQ](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1143). It works transparently and automatically, you don't have to do anything else.

Comment: But how is it shared between my team members? Should we all login to the same account or what?

Comment: @Garkbit, it's not for sharing between team members, it's for sharing between your several machines.